# RadioButtonMenuItem for java.awt.Menu

Tags: java, radio-button, awt, menuitem

In my java AWT (not Swing) application I use java.awt.MenuBar.

And I need use different checkboxes and radiobuttons inside the menu items.

I found java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem and successfully use it.

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

Menu menuSettings = new Menu("Settings");

Menu menuSettingsMenuGrid = new Menu("Grid");
CheckboxMenuItem menuCheckboxShowGrid = new CheckboxMenuItem("Show");
CheckboxMenuItem menuCheckboxHotspots = new CheckboxMenuItem("Hotspots");  
menuSettingsMenuGrid.add(menuCheckboxShowGrid)
menuSettingsMenuGrid.add(menuCheckboxHotspots)
menuSettings.add(menuSettingsMenuGrid);

menuBar.add(menuSettings);

mApplicationFrame.setMenuBar(menuBar);
```

But I can't find RadioButton. But I really need to use it in awt Menu. What can help me?

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: @camickr Because it's not clear if he's using a Swing or AWT menu (*"In my java swing application*") and seeing what part of the code he needs help completing will remove the need to post guesses as answers, which is always bad.

Comment: @camickr Not really, see the citing I gave.

Comment: @user1803551, added mcve

Comment: @Pavlik, 1) It would have been nice to remove all Swing references to remove all confusion. 2) that is not an "MCVE". You can't compile or execute that code. 3) AWT doesn't even support a radio button as a regular component, so you will also be out of luck trying to find a radio button for a menu.

Comment: @camickr it's a bit harder.. My app work with OpenGL. I tried build FX app, but it was failure. But with swing JMenu I had some problems (menu was covered by OpenGL canvas). And I had to use awt Menu. And in my toolbar I want to put language settings (radio group). Any ideas?

Comment: As camickr said, there are no direct radio buttons in AWT, but check boxes offer the same behavior. Use a [CheckboxGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html) to allow only 1 to be selected at a time. Use separators for the menu to show the user that those checkboxes behave as a group.

Comment: Why was the FX application a failure? JavaFX supports OpenGL.

Comment: @user1803551, I can't use CheckboxGroup in Menu, cause it's not MenuItem. Should I write my own CheckboxMenuItemGroup with CheckBoxMenuItems?

Comment: @user1803551, Don't know exactly what problem was with JavaFX. Maybe problems with library JOGL. But when I puted JOGL canvas in FX - it was white scene and nothig else.

Comment: You are right, create your own managing group. Use the source code of any of the AWT, Swing or FX groups as reference if you need.

Comment: I suggest you post a question about the JavaFX problem separately. There's a decent chance someone will be able to answer it.

Comment: @user1803551, Thanks for helping, friend!

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't find RadioButton. But I really need to use it in awt Menu. What can help me?

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuBar;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AWTMenuSample {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Frame frame = new Frame("AWT Menu");
    MenuBar bar = new MenuBar();
    Menu menu = new Menu("Settings");

    ActionListener actionPrinter = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Action [" + e.getActionCommand() + "] performed!\n");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    MenuItem menuItemShow = new MenuItem("Show");
    menuItemShow.addActionListener(actionPrinter);
    menu.add(menuItemShow);

    MenuItem menuItemHotspots = new MenuItem("Hotspots");
    menuItemHotspots.addActionListener(actionPrinter);
    menu.add(menuItemHotspots);

    bar.add(menu);
    frame.setMenuBar(bar);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

You can write your own algorithm to group actions in `ActionListener` event.